# Python: Where to place the config file in an API

Tags: python

I am working on an API, I just want to know what is the best place for config file which the user will provide for api to work. 
Basically I am working on getting tweets and I want the user to provide configurations(API credentials)

Comment: An API using what technology? This is far too broad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A common location for config files is in a folder in the User's home directory; e.g. `~/.config/my_api_config.cfg`, or `~/.my_api/config.cfg` etc...

There is nothing stopping you from requiring the user to put the file in a very specific location e.g., `/must/be/this/exact/folder/config.cfg`

Often time programs will search a few places to see if a config file exists, e.g.,

1. `same/directory/as/script/using/api/my_api_config.cfg` (per script config)
2. `~/.config/my_api_config.cfg` (per user config; could be
       anywhere else in specified user directory)
3. `/etc/my_api/config.cfg`
       (system-wide config)